# Fancybox not working in MVC 5 site - why am I getting a 403 error on ~/Content/fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

As stated.  The site works perfectly locally, but when deployed to SmarterAsp.Net, the images appear to be missing the CSS from the ~/Content folder, and I am getting a 403 Forbidden error on ~/Content/fancybox. I've never used a subfolder in ~/Content before ...is there something that I'm supposed to do to make it accessible?  This is an unsecured, no user login or registration, web site and the request is http (not https).

The 403 error:
[image]

Local dev box:
[image]

As deployed at SmarterAsp.Net:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OK ... I found the answer to my problem.  I was including the Fancybox styles and scripts in style and script bundles, and that worked on my local dev box.  But for deployment to the server, it seems that bundles do not work.  When I moved include the Fancybox CSS and script in the view itself, e.g. index.cshtml, then suddenly the Fancybox worked both locally and when deployed to the live server.  I do not know why, since other bundles worked fine (and did not depend on any subfolders in Scripts or Conten), Fancybox did not ...the only difference that I can see is that it depended upon a subfolder in Content while the others did not.  Regardless, moving the includes into the view fixed it all.